# How do I find the correct array and push data into meteor.users custom array field in mongodb with meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

How to I find right course_id and and push a "myclass2" to classes_id field which is an array?

I have got this but it added an extra row to classes

```
let data = Meteor.users.update({_id: Meteor.userId(), "classes.course_id": course_id}, {
   $push: {
        "classes": {
            "classes_id": [class_name]
        }
    }}
)
```

Wrong update:

```
{
  "_id": "RoFFcaAfXBeR2napZ",
  "emails": [
    {
      "address": "tong@gmail.com",
      "verified": false
    }
  ],
  "classes": [
      {
         "course_id": "svesvinfdsgrvnekuktndvsk",
         "classes_id": ["myclass1"]
      },
      {
         "course_id": "rgjjgdcrvnevghjcdvbbvddv",
         "classes_id": ["myclass1"]
      },
      {
         "classes_id": ["myclass2"]<----wrong update
      },
  ],
  "courses": [
    "qwmZdgQbrZ3rmHdN8"
  ]
}
```

Before Adding

```
{
  "_id": "RoFFcaAfXBeR2napZ",
  "emails": [
    {
      "address": "tong@gmail.com",
      "verified": false
    }
  ],
  "classes": [
      {
         "course_id": "svesvinfdsgrvnekuktndvsk",
         "classes_id": ["myclass1"]
      },
      {
         "course_id": "rgjjgdcrvnevghjcdvbbvddv",
         "classes_id": ["myclass1"]
      },
  ],
  "courses": [
    "qwmZdgQbrZ3rmHdN8"
  ]
}
```

How do I achieve this? Add myclass2 to classes_id if i can find course_id

```
{
  "_id": "RoFFcaAfXBeR2napZ",
  "emails": [
    {
      "address": "tong@gmail.com",
      "verified": false
    }
  ],
  "classes": [
      {
         "course_id": "svesvinfdsgrvnekuktndvsk",
         "classes_id": ["myclass1", "myclass2"]<----correct
      },
     {
         "course_id": "rgjjgdcrvnevghjcdvbbvddv",
         "classes_id": ["myclass1"]
      },
  ],
  "courses": [
    "qwmZdgQbrZ3rmHdN8"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [positional `$` operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_).

```js
function addClassId(userId, courseId, classId) {
  c1.update({
    _id: userId,
    'classes.course_id': courseId
  }, {
    $push: {
      'classes.$.classes_id': classId
    }
  });
};
```

It will get the first match from the `classes` array and push `classId` into its `classes_id` array.

Comment: Then you should [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). This makes others understand that the issue is resolved (even from the search) and is, therefore, a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

This works!

```
let data = Meteor.users.update({_id: Meteor.userId(), "classes.course_id": course_id}, {
     $push: {"classes.$.classes_id": class_name}
})
```